# How to display which AND criteria failed in an excel nested AND formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula that reads as follows:

`=AND(A2 = 1, B2 = 2, C2 = 3)`

This results in a `FALSE` value. I can use evaluate formula to understand which condition caused the `AND` to return a `FALSE` value. However, I want to display the column(s) that caused the `AND` to fail.

So in this case, lets say `A2<>1 and B2<>2` which causes the criteria to return `FALSE`. I want to display this in a new column. So column `D`(for example) would display `A,B`.

Is there anyway to go about doing this without a macro? I racked my brains and could only come up with complicated nested `IF` statements to do this.

Comment: `=if(a2 = 1, "", "A") & if(b2 = 2, "", "B") & if(c2 = 3, "", "C")`?

Comment: That would work if there was only 1 column that caused it to result in ```FALSE```. It might be the case that multiple columns don't satisfy the criteria

Comment: No, that would work for any number of columns.

Comment: Yes. I get it now. My bad, I forgot "&" is the concatenate operator. Thanks a lot :) . I spent so much time on this that I forgot such a simple fact!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TEXTJOIN` function comes in handy here:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF(A2 <> 1, "A", ""), IF(B2 <> 2, "B", ""), IF(C2 <> 3, "C", ""))
```

This would generate a CSV list of the columns which did not match, and `TEXTJOIN` gracefully handles the separator as well as edge cases.

Comment: Fun alternative: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:C2<>{1;2;3},{"A";"B";"C"},""))` < CSE entered through

Comment: I agree, suppose `TEXTJOIN` is their attempt though :)